# How to measure the angle of the rectangular marker on a rotating plane by an angled camera?

Tags: c++, opencv, angle, perspective, measure

I am developing an application. In this application there is a rectangular red object on a rotating flat surface. I can accurately detect this red object. I rotate it at 10 degree angles and measure how many degrees the camera makes over and over again., but I've seen a wide variation in the angle values ​​I measured when the camera looked angled with respect to the surface.

I used the findHomography () and warpPerspective () opencv methods to fix this, but I didn't get the exact result I wanted. Because these two methods after taking 4 points and paste these points always to the same point that I have determined.

I wonder if we could do something like that according to the angle that the camera is looking at, you can fix the shape of the rectangle with the whole picture, such as rectangle edges can be given "A" degrees from x, "B" degrees from y and "C" degrees from z, but will it also maintain the degree of angle with the camera? Then I'll measure the angle in the rectified rectangle. I shortly, in short, I need to correct the rectangle according to the angle of the camera and measure the angle of the rectangle relative to the camera. But I don't know how far the camera stands. I have to do this in a whole picture, not a single object..

Thank you for your help...

I wil share some code and images

```
`for (int getKey = 0; getKey < 36; getKey++)
    {
        ret = turnMotor("btnSetActPosZero", "true");
        Sleep(1000);

        ret = turnMotor("btnAbsMove", "true");
        Sleep(3000);


        for (int imageCnt = 0; key != 'q', imageCnt < dongu; imageCnt++)
        {
            // Get the image
            Image rawImage;
            t_error = t_camera.RetrieveBuffer(&rawImage);
            if (t_error != PGRERROR_OK) { t_error.PrintErrorTrace(); return -1; }

            Image rgbImage;
            rawImage.Convert(FlyCapture2::PIXEL_FORMAT_BGR, &rgbImage);

            cv::Mat imageUndistorted;
            unsigned int rowBytes = (double)rgbImage.GetReceivedDataSize() / (double)rgbImage.GetRows();
            cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(rgbImage.GetRows(), rgbImage.GetCols(), CV_8UC3, rgbImage.GetData(), rowBytes);
            cv::Mat res = image.clone();

            cv::initUndistortRectifyMap(intrinsic, distCoeffs, cv::Mat(), intrinsic, cv::Size(image.cols, image.rows), CV_32FC1, map1, map2);
            cv::remap(image, imageUndistorted, map1, map2, cv::INTER_CUBIC);
            cv::Mat imageI = cv::Mat(imageUndistorted, bbox);

            // Split eye image into 3 channels.
            vector<Mat>bgr(3);
            split(imageI, bgr);

            float angleRefAngleKirmizi = 0.0;

            {
                cv::Mat mask = (bgr[0] > 160) & (bgr[1] > 175);
                vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
                vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;

                cv::Mat maskRedBefore = (bgr[2] > 175);

                Mat maskRed = maskRedBefore - mask;
                int index = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    index = 0;
                    findContours(maskRed, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
                    if (contours.size() == 0) { return -1; };

                    double maxArea = contourArea(contours[0]);
                    int index = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if (contourArea(contours[i]) > maxArea) {
                            maxArea = contourArea(contours[i]);
                            index = i;
                        }
                    }
                    floodFill(maskRed, Point(0, 0), Scalar(255, 255, 255));
                    drawContours(maskRed, contours, index, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, 8, vector<cv::Vec4i>(), 0, cv::Point());
                    floodFill(maskRed, contours[index][int(contours[index].size() / 2)], Scalar(0, 0, 0));
                    floodFill(maskRed, Point(0, 0), Scalar(0, 0, 0));

                }

                Mat mask2;
                cv::Vec4f myLine;
                vector<cv::Point> nonZeroCoordinates;
                cv::findNonZero(maskRed, nonZeroCoordinates);

                if (nonZeroCoordinates.size() != 0)
                {
                    cv::fitLine(nonZeroCoordinates, myLine, CV_DIST_L2, 0, 0.01, 0.01);
                    angleRefAngleKirmizi = atan2(myLine[1], myLine[0]) < 0 ? atan2(myLine[1], myLine[0]) + CV_PI : atan2(myLine[1], myLine[0]);

                    cv::putText(imageI, to_string(angleRefAngleKirmizi * 180 / CV_PI), cv::Point(myLine[2], myLine[3]), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX, 0.3, cvScalar(0, 255, 255), 1, CV_AA);
                    line(imageI, cv::Point(myLine[2], myLine[3]), cv::Point(myLine[2] + myLine[0] * 100, myLine[3] + myLine[1] * 100), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1, 8);

                    out_transform << to_string(angleRefAngleKirmizi * 180 / CV_PI) << endl;
                }

            }

            imshow("image", imageI);
            key = cv::waitKey(1);
        }
`
```

and composite images of the rectangle are simulated in some respects n .[shown  that the image combination of the rectangle at some angles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoRdy.jpg) and rotating flat surface show[rotating flat surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGdby.jpg)

and also add code that do two opencv methods.

```
            vector<cv::Point2d> approx;
            approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[index]), approx, 3, true);

            if (approx.size() == 0) return -14;
            for (int j = 0; j < approx.size(); j++)
            {
                cv::putText(imageI, to_string(j), approx[j], cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX, 0.6, cvScalar(0, 0, 0), 1, CV_AA);
                line(imageI, approx[j], approx[(j+1)% approx.size()], cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), 1, 8);

            }


            vector<Point2f> pts_src;
            pts_src.push_back(Point2f(0, 0));
            pts_src.push_back(Point2f(80, 0));
            pts_src.push_back(Point2f(80, 30));
            pts_src.push_back(Point2f(0, 30));


            // Calculate Homography between source and destination points
            Mat h = findHomography(approx, pts_src);

            // Warp source image
            warpPerspective(imageI, HomogImage, h, HomogImage.size(), CV_INTER_LINEAR);
```

Comment: I think you can take a peek in Chapter 11 here: https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/files/OReilly%20Learning%20OpenCV.pdf they descibe there how to find out camera position in relation to the object.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and showing the way I have to go , I looked at the chapter you said and the subsection  bird's eye view is I want. But I am not able to manage measure the angle perfectly. And I've done some experiments, sometimes I've observed that if the motor rotates at high speeds, it makes a mistake up to 1 degree. Now I try to stereo camera usage.